# What is 'really_inline' exactly?

Tags: c++, optimization

While browsing github I stumbled on "[really_inline](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson/blob/master/src/generic/json_scanner.h)" keyword and I was wondering what is it exactly?

Obviously, if it lives by its name, it makes 100% sure to embed the function and remove the caller/callee in the assembly output, but I want to know if it is specific to any compiler or else and how is this done.

Comment: It's a lie for a start. It's impossible to inline a recursive function, or a function called via a pointer.

Comment: It's a macro that expands (conditionally) to non-standard extensions supported by some but not all compilers.   Not all compilers support such a thing, and (if they do) different compilers support different syntax.   You'll need to read documentation for your particular compiler to have any guarantees that it will compile, let alone work.   If you use it, you'll need to accept that it may not compile (let alone work) if your code is ever ported to a different compiler or to a different host system - or even if your compiler is updated sometime in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this case it's a macro -- simdjson defines it conditionally on whether it is msvc:

[here](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson/blob/2a1f8fa8f16d3ef5bc32ae8fe3cc105f6a3e0fba/singleheader/simdjson.h#L313) (msvc):

```cpp
  #define really_inline __forceinline
```

and [here](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson/blob/2a1f8fa8f16d3ef5bc32ae8fe3cc105f6a3e0fba/singleheader/simdjson.h#L334) (not msvc):

```cpp
  #define really_inline inline __attribute__((always_inline, unused))
```

Comment: If the compiler is not MSVC, then `really_inline` is not guaranteed to even compile.  The `__attribute__(....)` is a non-standard extension supported by some compilers (e.g. gcc/g++) but not others.

Comment: @Peter on unknown compilers it probably expands to `inline`. It's a very common pattern to have macros that expand to nothing if the compiler is unknown, so I don't see your point.

Comment: @Ayxan - Look at the link given in the answer.   As the answer describes, the macro is conditionally defined one way for MSVC, and another way for all other compilers.  There's no default for unknown compilers.

Comment: @Peter oh, sorry, I didn't notice that. Doesn't seem to be a very bright idea then.